# Save form details to google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a business website having a form.. Currently my form details are sent to email.. I want that when form is submitted the details should be added in google sheet directly. because it is hard to check every mail. plz help.

`HTML`

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form" name="myForm"  id="myForm"  action="sendmail.php">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required />
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Mobile No.*" required pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}">
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
            </form>
```

`pHp`

```
<?PHP

$name = $_POST["name"];
//$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$to = "yourmail@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for project";
$headers = "From: $name\n";

$message = "This form has been submitted to project.\n
Name : $name;

Mobile No. : $phone";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('Location: http://websites.com/thank_you.html');
 $thank_you = "Thank You For your interest. <br>We will Contact you soon";
 echo  "$thank_you .";

?>
```

Comment: why don't you use google forms if the objective is to save it to google sheet directly?

Comment: i have to add form in my website. like http://vnwproperties.com/dhayari/ here we have enquire now form